Which resource qualifiers should I use for devices having similar screen sizes but showing views in different sizes?
I am working with views in xml in Android development, and I noticed that some devices with similar screen sizes (both in terms of DPI and pixels) show the UI of the app differently. For example, a OnePlus Nord 2T shows the text and UI views in a much larger size than compared to a Moto G9 Plus. Both use the normal scaling setting of the display selectable in the phone's settings. I tried using screen-size specific layouts in xml, however it does not make any sense, since both devices have similar screen sizes both in pixels and dpi.
What is the cause for this view size discrepancy, and which specific screen resource qualifiers should I use in my xml layouts so to reflect this?

There is also the system font scale setting where you can change the font size. That also has an effect on the UI and can make the same app look different.

Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am aware of this and both phones do use the same "standard" size scaling. Nonetheless, views and texts are shown in different sizes.

OnePlus and Moto are different brands of phones. There is no single "standard" size scaling across brands. Beyond that, we cannot really help you much without a [mcve] showing what you are trying and screenshots showing your results.
